# SSMS 2019 large queries debugging

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am recently involved with supporting customers with very large MSSQL databases (terabyte) which means sometimes queries can take hours to complete.

What is the best way to debug sql queries? What I mean is, suppose you have a 1000-line sql query with sub queries etc that takes one hour to complete and you end up and with a "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2021-03-01 00:00:00' to data type int".

The live query statistics of SMSS suddenly at 88% of execution gives this error. The query has statements that contain that date are all over the query. Is there any way of horizontal step debugger is SMSS in which you can see on what particular line of the query is the error?

I know about the Stored Procedure debugging functionalities but what about simple queries? How can someone manage to have a better view of what's happening when they are executed? There is no way of a step debugger or something in sql queries, right?

Comment: Have you considered `try_convert` ?

Comment: Please share the estimated query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most likely you have an implicit conversion which is throwing an error.**

The easiest way to spot this, especially on a large or long query, is to generate an estimated execution plan.

Then you can look at one of the following:

- On the `SELECT` node, you will find **Warnings**, this will tell which expression it is, although it doesn't tell you which part of the plan it is
- You can search the nodes one by one
- You can right-click, open the XML, and search it for `CONVERT_IMPLICIT`, this will give you the exact node. You may have to follow it through a bit to work out which part of the query it relates to.
  SentryOne Plan Explorer can show you where the XML relates to in the graphical plan.

---

**What caused it is most likely:**

- An accidental comparison between the wrong columns, or
- `DATEADD` or `DATEDIFF` with incorrect parameters, or
- `UNION ALL` or `VALUES` clause which is combining the two different data types

Comment: Thank you All! I think that Sentryone Plan Explorer is a much promising tool that i didnt knew its existance .I am really surprized with its capabilities and at least i have a plan tree instead of a plan diagram. But Charlieface is this tool free ? I see that in the text data of the query it shows some of the lines and then it says /*...<TRUNCATED>...*/ Does this has to do with paying for the full version of the tool ?

Comment: Yes it is free. The actual SQL query text is truncated by the server if it is very large IIRC, the rest of the XML should be fine (check in SSMS to confirm)

Answer (score 0):

This is more generalized sql advice than specific SMSS advice (since I don't use the program)

You can test your subqueries separately to see if they're valid.

You should also test your queries on a smaller localized data set. This will give you rapid responses and allow you to test/debug more easily. You should never test queries against a live data set. (You really don't want to have the conversation with your boss of how recent the last backup was made, trust me on that one)

Performance is to be done with a more accurate data set, or several sizes to get an accurate feel for performance scaling.

Use the EXPLAIN and ANALYZE to get a more in depth view of what the database will do with your query.

Answer (score 0):

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2021-03-01 00:00:00' to data type int"

This is a *horrible* error to have to deal with, speaking from personal experience.

Basically, you need to fix the data or the query.  And it takes a bit of work.  If you are lucky, then your query has no implicit conversions.  If that is the case, you can simply replace `cast()`/`convert()` with `try_cast()` and `try_convert()`.

Unfortunately, there probably are implicit conversions in your query.  This means that something is amiss in the data model, usually a string is used to store a number or a date -- and the user of the data doesn't realize that the wrong type os being used.  And somewhere along the way, someone put an inappropriate value in the table.

This takes a lot of debugging.  I would start by investigating the data types of each column being used and looking at the operators/functions to be sure they are appropriate for the data type.